# Display multiple sections using data attributes and ID

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to display multiple sections based on data- attributes that are mapped to a list

```
<!--Flavor List-->
<ul>
<li class="active" data-related="flavor-info1">VANILLA</li>
<li data-related="flavor-info2">CHOCOLATE</li>
<li data-related="flavor-info3">STRAWBERRY</li>
<li data-related="flavor-info4">WILD BERRIES</li>
</ul>
```

Based on the above attributes the corresponding images will be displayed.

```
<!-- Flavor Images-->
<div>
<div class="flavor-info visible" id="flavor-info1">
<img src="../img/vanilla-info.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">                    </div>
<div class="flavor-info" id="flavor-info2">
<img src="../img/choco-info.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
</div>
<div class="flavor-info" id="flavor-info3">
<img src="../img/strawberry-info.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
</div>
<div class="flavor-info" id="flavor-info4">
<img src="../img/berry-info.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

I tried the following jQuery and it works fine.

```
$(".flavor-list li").each(function() {
$(this).click(function(){
$("div[id=" + $(this).attr("data-related") + "]").addClass("visible");
});
});
```

I have to show another independent sections that are not related to the images with the same data- attributes in the list.

```
<!-- Flavor Description-->
<div class="flavor-desc">This is chocolate</div>
<div class="flavor-desc">This is Vanilla</div>
<div class="flavor-desc">This is Strawberry</div>
```

Is it possible to add one more data- attribute that will separately display the description. The expectation here is to show both the images and description in one click.

Comment: Change `id` to `class` and image and description would have `class="flavor-info1"`.

Comment: Sure...can have as many data attributes as you need